# File is not displaying in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer, forge

In First time, I have uploaded the Naviswork/Revit file and done following processess like forge bucket generation, token creation,SVF conversion.

I am passing URN for loading the file in forge viewer and its working fine.

Next day(after 24 hours) i am passing the same URN to loading the file.
But the file is not displaying in forge viewer.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [OSS Retention Policy](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/) to check your buck policy while creating it. If the policy **Transient** or **Temporary**, then it's expected. All files uploaded to such kind of buckets, they will be removed after the designed deletion time, but the translation result will be retained on the server unless you called the [DELETE :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/)
.

So, you can still view the translated result with Forge viewer if you know the URN. Therefore, we will advise you to backup the URN for viewing the model later.
Now you can upload the same file to the bucket again to get URN, then keep the URN  somewhere to prevent this situation.